# Media queries don't work when menu is slidedown with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a navigationsbar. If the display is smaller than `856px`, the design will change (media-queries). Now you can press on `Menü` and the navigation will slide down. Look at the 3 steps here:

[image]

You can test it by yourself. Here is the link: [mypage](http://skeptar1.lima-city.de/index.php?content=create_tutorial)

**My Code:**

```js
    $("#nav_menu_header").click(function(){
        if($(".navbar_li").is(':visible')){
            $(".navbar_li").slideToggle("slow");
        }
        else{
            $(".navbar_li").slideDown("slow");
        }
    })
```

```css
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 125, 0);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


.navbar_ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar_li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.navbar_a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar_a:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 125, 0);
}

#nav_menu_header{
    display: none;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 125, 0);
}

.symbol{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#nav_menu_header:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
        <nav>
            <a id="nav_menu_header"><i class="fa fa-home symbol"></i>Menü</a>
            <ul class="navbar_ul">
                <li class="navbar_li"><a class="navbar_a" href="index.php?content=create_tutorial">Tutorial erstellen</a></li>
                <li class="navbar_li"><a class="navbar_a" href="index.php?content=all_tutorial">Alle Tutorials</a></li>
                <li class="navbar_li"><a class="navbar_a" href="#">Suche</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Mediq Query:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 855px) {
 nav{
  border: none;
 }
 .navbar_ul{
     list-style-type: none;
 }

 .navbar_li{
  display: none;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 125, 0);
 }

 .navbar_a{
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 10px 0px;
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     padding-left: 30px;
     transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
 }

 .navbar_a:hover{
     color: rgb(255, 125, 0);
 }
 
 #nav_menu_header{
  display: block;
 }

}
```

How can i get the normal navigationbar, if I press the `x`?

Comment: I think it is related with your [tag:jquery] code.

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in the comment it is related to [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). We will need to add resize event as follows:

```
$("#nav_menu_header").click(function(){
        if($(".navbar_li").is(':visible')){
            $(".navbar_li").css('display','none');
        }
        else{
            $(".navbar_li").css('display','block');
        }
    });
$(window).resize(function(){
if($("#nav_menu_header").is(':visible')){ 
  $(".navbar_li").css('display','none');
}
else{
  $(".navbar_li").css('display','inline-block');
}
});
```

Checkout this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/hafoke/3/)